# Rewrite codeigniter URL with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite the URL by `Apache mod-rewrite` in Codeigniter

The page name is `example.com/pages/page1`
and i need to rename it by `example.com/welcome.html`

I wrote this rules in **`htaccess`** file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pages/page1$ welcome.html [PT,L]
```

It doesn't work. How can i do that?.

Comment: So if you directly go to `example.com/welcome.html` does it show up fine?

Comment: I used Codeigniter "Routing" http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html And i did what i need :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sys.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

assumming that **index.php** is your index page.

and change in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```